# presigned url with content-dispostion with aws cloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to make presigned url with AWS Cloudfront, but i don't understand how to change a name of downloaded file.
I know that with 'aws-sdk' we can pass content-disposition in params, but how to pass content-disposition with CloudFront. I've used 'aws-cloudfront-sign' and couldn't find any info how to change filename with CF presigned url.
I know that we can add content-diposition in header, but it's not suitable. I want the link to contain needed filename like in 'aws-sdk'.